# how to initialize JUnit test classes before running in parallel

Tags: java, junit, parallel-processing, junit4

I am trying to execute JUnit tests in parallel using the [ParallelComputer](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/experimental/ParallelComputer.html) experimental feature, however I do not know how to pre-initialize each of the test classes before kicking off the tests.

The classic example of how these are supposed to be used is as follows (as shown in the following GitHub [link](https://gist.github.com/djangofan/4997487)).  Per the example, how do I initialize the `ParallelTest1` and `ParallelTest2` classes with shared data before starting the parallel thread testing.  I was able to do this via constructors in each of the classes, however I need to make sure that both classes are fully initialized before the run starts.  This problem is probably not specific to the Parallel nature of how I wish to perform the testing but more likely how to use some special keywords to order prevent initialized objects from starting until required.  Ideally the example `ParallelComputerTest` could have this shared data initialized in its constructor, however in that case, how could the nested static parallel test classes get access to this instance data?

```
public class ParallelComputerTest {  

   @Test  
    public void test() {      
      Class[] cls={ParallelTest1.class,ParallelTest2.class };  

      //Parallel among classes  
      JUnitCore.runClasses(ParallelComputer.classes(), cls);  

      //Parallel among methods in a class  
      JUnitCore.runClasses(ParallelComputer.methods(), cls);  

      //Parallel all methods in all classes  
      JUnitCore.runClasses(new ParallelComputer(true, true), cls);     
    }  
   public static class ParallelTest1{  
      @Test public void a(){}  
      @Test public void b(){}  
   }  
   public static class ParallelTest2{  
      @Test public void a(){}  
      @Test public void b(){}  
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@Before` for set ups and `@After` for clean ups.

For example to test console output I set up streams before and clean result after test like this:

```
@Before
public void setUpStreams() {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));
}

@After
public void cleanUpStreams() {
    System.setOut(null);
    System.setErr(null);
}
```

**NOTE:** this can cause problems with `TestSuite`, dunno if also with `ParallelTest`. If you experience some troubles AND you use JUnit 4.7 or higher you might like to check [this link to rules feature](https://www.infoq.com/news/2009/07/junit-4.7-rules)

Comment: so do the Before & After belong to the ParallelComputerTest  or to the ParallelTest[n] per my example.  If the former how can I shared this initialized data with the ParallelTest[n] class instances once they are constructed?

Comment: if will run before and after each method execution that is marked with `@Test` not the static ones...